# Updating dataframes in a dictionary

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like the following,

```
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+
|           placekey|naics_code|       visits_by_day|date_range_start|date_range_end|
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+
|zzy-222@627-wby-z9f|    445120|[41,126,72,96,110...|      2018-12-31|    2019-01-07|
|zzw-223@627-s6k-fzz|    722410|[25,22,92,74,98,5...|      2018-12-31|    2019-01-07|
|223-222@627-s8r-8gk|    722410|[70,82,58,80,106,...|      2018-12-31|    2019-01-07|
|                ...|       ...|                 ...|             ...|           ...|
|22j-222@627-vty-5cq|    722511|    [11,5,9,5,4,6,5]|      2019-01-28|    2019-02-04|
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

This dataframe has a 9 unique naics_code and my goal is to add few more columns using other columns and partition it by the naics_code to create 9 different csv files. I am trying to partition the dataframe first and then add the columns, because I think this will somehow make the work more efficient, because I can get away with grouping the data by the key (let me know if this is a bad idea). So I created a dictionary of dataframes and I tried to add a new column to all of the partitioned dataframes in a loop,

```
for x in df_dict.values():
    x = x.withColumn('new_col', udf_some_func(x['col1'], x['col2']))
```

But when I looked at the dataframes, the new column is not there, but when I print x.show() in the for loop, it does show the new column. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within each iteration of the loop, `x` is a local variable. Reassigning `x` will make it point to the new dataframe you created, but the old dataframe in the dict will remain untouched. You probably mean to do something like

```py
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    df[k] = v.withColumn('new_col', udf_some_func(v['col1'], v['col2']))
```